# Lines in Grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb C^6$. Let $V \in \mathrm{Gr}(3,\mathbb C^6)$ be such that $$V=\left<\sum_{i=1}^6a_ix_i, \sum_{i=1}^6b_ix_i, \sum_{i=1}^6c_ix_i\right>$$ and $W \in\mathrm{Gr}(3, \mathbb C^6)$ be such that $$W=\left<\sum_{i=1}^3a_ix_i-\sum_{i=4}^6a_ix_i, \sum_{i=1}^3b_ix_i-\sum_{i=4}^6b_ix_i, \sum_{i=1}^3c_ix_i -\sum_{i=4}^6c_ix_i\right>.$$ Then $V$ and $W$ represent two points in $\mathbb P(\bigwedge^3\mathbb C^6)$ denote them by $[V]$ and $[W]$. My guess is that the line joining these two points in $\mathbb P(\bigwedge^3\mathbb C^6)$ intersects $\mathrm{Gr}(3, \mathbb C^6)$ exactly at two points namely at $[V]$ and $[W]$. Is there a way to prove my claim ? Thanks.

Comment: I am a bit confused. The dimension of $Gr(3, C^6)$ is 9 and $\dim P(\wedge^3 C^6) = 19$. Doesn't $\dim Gr(3, C^6) \cap L \ge 8$ imply that there are infinitely many points in the intersection?

Comment: Why do you say that the dimension of the intersection is bigger than 8 ?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I think I mseed up dim and codim. I do not have an answer to you question, but I will try again.